# SharePoint Search in its own Site Collection

Tags: search

Would I have to create a separate scope if I want to only search in its own site collection?

I want to be able to distinguish searches to the entire site and just the site collection it is in.

How can one go about this ?

Thanks.

Note, this is not FAST Search, just OOTB basic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify you basically want:

- Search this Site (i.e. SPWeb within an SPSite)
- Search this Site Collection (All SPSite)

You get the "This Site" functionality OOTB (also get "This List"). Presuming you have a SharePoint Search SA, then you would probably need to create a scope for just the specific site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a search scope called "This Site" in the default search?

(Might be only in Search Server Express).